# offline documentation

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS documentation servers were down this morning (Nov 17, 2011) from about 10:00 am to 1:30 pm EST (at least from Pittsburgh). Is there any way to access documentation pages offline? Maybe a debian documentation package or simply a tarball? I am a pretty heavy ROS user and Google cache pages take a while to load sometimes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11974/offline-documentation/) by [debadeepta](https://answers.ros.org/users/1400/debadeepta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-17**:
yes - i couldnt access ros and PCL sites from Russia :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a wiki mirror maintained by Felix Endres at Freiburg: http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/

And Felix documented how he does it in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/977/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-18**:
This thread lists a bunch of new mirrors. https://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20111118.203022.664c10a8.en.html